# Function always returns null even with ISNULL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION HARDCODERS.getKilosDisponiblesViaje(@Viaje int)

RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 

(
select Micro.KG_Disponibles - SUM(Encomienda.Cant_KG) as KGDisponibles
from HARDCODERS.Micro, HARDCODERS.Viaje, HARDCODERS.Encomienda, HARDCODERS.PasajeEncomienda
where Viaje.Cod_Viaje = @Viaje AND Viaje.Patente = Micro.Patente AND PasajeEncomienda.Cod_Viaje = @Viaje
    AND PasajeEncomienda.Cod_PasajeEncomienda = Encomienda.Cod_PasajeEncomienda
group by Micro.KG_Disponibles,Micro.Patente
)

GO
```

It works fine if I have rows in Encomienda. However, if I don't the function will always return null.

I added an ISNULL to the SUM, also tried inside of it and it keeps returning null if there are no rows in Encomienda.

Micro.KG_Disponibles always has a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off stop using implicit joins. Once you have done that you can use a LEFT JOIN which will probably solve your problem.

Comment: LEFT JOIN solved the problem. But don't implicit joins work as JOINS? What I am trying to say is that even if I do a join, the ISNULL should have worked :/